# Jmeter: testing multiple database connections from csv file

Tags: csv, jmeter

Following is the test scenario I need to run in Jmeter:
1

1. csv file containing multiple Database hostnames/sids
2. JDBC connection Configuration-> After I add variables names (for data read successfully from csv file), it does not translate variables into actual values.
   as in screen shot.
   [image]

This is because Jmeter executes JDBC connection configuration Before CSV database configuration.

Any other way I can have Jmeter read Database connection details for multiple DB servers from a CSV and test DB connectivity for each DB?
I cannot define DB connections as user property (__P()) because there are too DB hosts.

In current setup, tree results show:

> Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Invalid connection
>   string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid" )

Any help will be highly appreciated.